# Bluemix deployment error using web gui: FAILED Invalid JSON response from server: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string

Tags: json, deployment, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, devops

I'm running a Liberty profile Bluemix hosted application.  I'm using a Jazzhub devops deployment pipeline with several stages, one for each target work space (dev, QA, test, production).

When using the devops deployment pipeline web-based gui, I can successfully deploy my chosen build to all stages except the last one (production). When I attempt to deploy the final pipeline stage to production it fails with the following cryptic error message:

> FAILED  Invalid JSON response from server: json: cannot unmarshal
>   number into Go value of type string

I have compared the final stage with the stages that are working and can find no difference other than the target itself. I have rebuilt the final stage from scratch a couple times to see if that would resolve the issue. However, I get the same error every time I try to deploy to the production target using the gui.

If I use the command line tools (i.e. cf login, cf push), the deployment completes without an error even using the exact same commands listed in the production stage's profile from the gui.

So while I can deploy to the target production work space, I am left without the handy gui indicator of what build is actually running in production at any given time. Also, I have to keep track of this information myself if I want to know what's running there.

I've seen similar questions regarding container deployment issues but I'm using the built-in Bluemix Liberty runtime and have no access to adjust details of container deployment like Docker version, etc.

Does anybody have any clue what might be causing this error or how I can troubleshoot the issue further?

Thanks

@crjenkins89 Full log looks like this, even with setting CF_TRACE=true:

```
Downloading artifacts...DOWNLOAD SUCCESSFUL
Target: https://api.ng.bluemix.net
  adding: wlp/ (stored 0%)
  adding: wlp/usr/ (stored 0%)
  adding: wlp/usr/servers/ (stored 0%)
  adding: wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/ (stored 0%)
  adding: wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml (deflated 56%)
  adding: wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/jvm.options (deflated 20%)
  adding: wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server-local.xml (deflated 53%)
  adding: wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/ (stored 0%)
  adding: wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/rccs.war (deflated 2%)
  adding: wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/rca_help.war (deflated 5%)
Using manifest file manifest-prod.yml

FAILED
Invalid JSON response from server: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string

Finished: FAILED

Stage has no runtime information
```

Comment: Is there anything else to the log besides the error message?  Would you be able to add the whole log to your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently fixed when the cf cli version used by the devops deployment pipeline was updated.  All stages are working properly now.